# Fade in/Fade out in Cocos 2d not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make a **fade in-fade out** effect in cocos 2d, using a black png image. Its to make a better way to show something, instead of the casual way...

Is something wrong on this code?

```
- (void) effectFade {

    CCSprite *effectScreen = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"black-iphone.png"];
    effectScreen.opacity = 0;

    [effectScreen runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                           [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1],
                           [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(hideOutShowIn)],
                           [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1],
                           [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finish)],
                           nil]];
    CCFadeTo *fadeIn = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1];
    CCFadeTo *fadeOut = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:1];

    CCSequence *fadeSequence = [CCSequence actionOne:fadeIn two:fadeOut];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify what is not working as expected, but it seems to me that you are not adding `effectScreen` to any layer or other node, so that it can be displayed.

As to the rest, the code seems correct to me (aside from `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, `fadeSequence` that are not used).

EDIT:

you are definitely *using* `effectScreen` in an ObjC/C sense; what you are not doing is adding it to your scene by doing something like:

```
[self addChild:effectScene];
```

(assuming `self` is your scene or another `CCNode` class).

The thing about not using `fadeSequence` is a bit different, since you are not using it in the ObjC/C sense: you define it and never ever reference it again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. So, the thing is that I don't utilize the effectScreen sprite? That's why in the CCSequence, a warning appears telling 'Unused variable 'fadeSequence' isn't it?

Comment: Great stuff. So I have to do this for example?
    ["MenuNameClass" addChild:effectScreen];   
cause a warning appear: Class method 'addchild' not found (return type defaults to "id")